# Arabic Translation not working on iOS 9, but does on iOS 10

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, nslocalizedstring, localizable.strings

I have an iOS app that has 3 localizations:

```
(lldb) po [[NSBundle mainBundle] localizations]
<__NSArrayM 0x170051a90>(
Base,
ar-001,
en
)
```

When I change my iOS 10 device to Arabic, the storyboards and strings are properly localized. On iOS 9 this is not the case. I dont understand why. This app is written in Objective-C and is compiled with Xcode 8.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had to replace my `Arabic (World) (ar-001)` localization for `Arabic (ar)`. Apparently `Arabic (World) (ar-001)` is new in Xcode 8 and iOS 10, and isn't supported on older iOS versions (and doesn't appear in Xcode 7).